# Is this fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I have some code that I don`t know in which language it is written in. I think it is in Fortran, but I want to be sure. And if it is Fortran, can somebody determine which Fortran it is? The name of the file is **AExtr.for** There is some code:

```
PROGRAM AEXTR
use DFLOGM
use DFLIB
implicit none
include 'AExtr.fd'
external ProgSel
external VectorPlot
c   external ContourPlot
external TimeHist
external Grid
type (dialog) dlg
integer retint, isel, i, argc
character*10 argv
logical retlog
character*50 PNAME,TPNAME
common /ProgSelV/ isel

CALL GETARG(0,PNAME)
i = INDEX(PNAME,'\',.true.)
TPNAME = PNAME(1:i)
PNAME = PNAME(1:i)//'Temp\'
retlog = CHANGEDIRQQ(PNAME)
...
END PROGRAM
```

Thank you

itelly

Comment: Yes, it's FORTRAN - note that a real programmer can write FORTRAN in any language.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is Fortran 90 or later with some non-standard extension function called (`GETARG`, `CHANGEDIRQQ`).

It seems to be in the fixed source form.  Note that this way written it is not a well formed fixed form source. The `c` in `c external` should be in the first column to act as a comment. The other statements should start at column 7 or later. Alternatively, if the `c` is a typo and shouldn't be there, it could be a free form source.

Comment: `CHANGEDIRQQ` is an Intel extension, part if the `IFPORT` module they provide if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

this code is QUICK WIN for windows GUI programming.